# Set object mode positon of rig to be exact of the edit mode positon

Tags: rigging

I currently adjusted the position of the bones of my rig in edit mode. Every time when I tab to object mode, the bones are slightly off. Re-adjusting the bones in edit mode only results in them still being off in object and pose mode.

The classical <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd> and <kbd>S</kbd> method (clearing transforms) does not work for me, it does not change anything at all with the rig. The rig is not even bound to the 3D model yet.

Does anyone know how to fix this? So the Object mode position of the bones and the whole rig are the exact same as the edit mode position?

Blend file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on your bone in pose mode

[image]

press "clear inverse" then "set inverse"

Comment: That solved it, thank you a thousand times for this :D

Comment: you are welcome!!!

Comment: Thank you again.
Do you maybe know why this issue appeared in the first place? So I can bypass it happening in the first place in the future.

Comment: Maybe read here https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/relationship/child_of.html it is pretty well explained

Comment: thank you for the link

Comment: Glad I could help